# Find all records with Hebrew names

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, performance, hebrew

I have a postgresql database with a users table, where each user has a name (in unicode). I'd like to find all users whose name contains at least one Hebrew character. I've thought using [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549012/how-to-tell-if-a-string-contains-characters-in-hebrew-using-php), e.g.

```
select * from users
where name ~ '[א-ת]';
```

Is there a more efficient approach than the regex? I have a B-tree index on the names column.

**Update**

Using the different indices with the `pg_trgm` module as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46517538/165753) by @FuzzyTree

```
      B-tree GIST  GIN
user  0.04   0.04  0.03
sys   0.02   0.04  0.01
total 0.06   0.08  0.04
```

Regarding disk size, the GIN index is 0.2x of the GIST one, and 0.8x of the B-tree. So, we have a winner here, at least for my use case. YMMV (e.g. I haven't benchmarked index creation and update). Version: postgres 9.6.

Comment: Come on, with more than 2k rep, you should already what we want and that you are likely to get more useful answers when you provide some code snippets.

Comment: @Jan, a snippet for what? I'm asking *what* to do, rather than *how* to do something. I can add a snippet for my current regex code if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a boolean column i.e. `is_hebrew_name` that you can update once using your regex and create a regular index on.

If you don't want to add another column and you're running v9.3 or higher, then consider using the `pg_trgm` module to create a `GIN` or `GIST` index on `name`

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON users USING GIST (name gist_trgm_ops);
```

> The pg_trgm module provides GiST and GIN index operator classes that
>   allow you to create an index over a text column for the purpose of
>   very fast similarity searches. These index types support the
>   above-described similarity operators, and additionally support
>   trigram-based index searches for LIKE, ILIKE, ~ and ~* queries.
>
> The index search works by extracting trigrams from the regular
>   expression and then looking these up in the index. The more trigrams
>   that can be extracted from the regular expression, the more effective
>   the index search is. Unlike B-tree based searches, the search string
>   need not be left-anchored.
>
> For both LIKE and regular-expression searches, keep in mind that a
>   pattern with no extractable trigrams will degenerate to a full-index
>   scan.
>
> The choice between GiST and GIN indexing depends on the relative
>   performance characteristics of GiST and GIN, which are discussed
>   elsewhere.

For more info see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll [test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830/postgresql-gin-or-gist-indexes#26398) both and will report the result.